# Do something if a list has a number greater than x

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following list so far: `mylist = [[4, 7, 3], [8, 4, 2], [5, 4, 6], [5, 3, 8]]`
Is it possible to do something like this:

"if mylist has a number greater than 9, print no

if mylist has a number between 1 and 9, print "yes"."

I get an error with the method I try to do it with: `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'`

Here is the code:

```
for number in mylist:
    if all(i >= 9 for i in mylist):
        print ("no")
    else:
        print("yes")
```

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. Have you tried anything? What happened? Give a [mcve].

Comment: 9 in `mylist` or 9 in each sublist? show the code as well as you traceback

Comment: So basically, I don't want any of the numbers in the list being greater than 9. I'll add my code in.

Comment: `i` is still a list, because you have a list of lists. You need to flatten the outer list or nest loops.